# Error unexpected double quote occur while Parshing Common apache Apache log file

Tags: apache-pig

I was trying to parse apache log :

```
159.142.136.231 - - [08/Aug/1995:21:56:04 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/ HTTP/1.0" 200 4673 
Code:
log = load "/myhdfs/project/TestLog.txt" USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.apachelog.ApacheCommonLogLoader AS (address, logname, user, time,method, uri, proto,status, bytes);
Error :
<line 1, column 9>  Unexpected character '"'
2015-12-12 00:49:10,187 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 1, column 9>  Unexpected character '"'.
```

I don't know why this error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using single quote ' instead of double when giving hdfs path

Comment: it worked.. i don`t know how.. how does it make the difference ?